# okhttp support for connection pooling in http2

Tags: okhttp

Does okhttp support connection pooling for http2 client ?
The offifical doc https://square.github.io/okhttp/ says this
"Connection pooling reduces request latency (if HTTP/2 isn’t available)".

Does okhttp has any way to configure the max concurrent streams allowed on a connection as per rfc https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.1.2 ? What is the default value for max concurrent streams sent by okhttp http2 client ? What happens when receiver sends refused stream error when max concurrent streams threshold is met ? Is it retried or request fails ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does okhttp has any way to configure the max concurrent streams allowed on a connection as per rfc https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-5.1.2 ?

Not currently.

> What is the default value for max concurrent streams sent by okhttp http2 client ?

This is honored.

> What happens when receiver sends refused stream error when max concurrent streams threshold is met ? Is it retried or request fails ?

OkHttp will fail the request all the way to the application. You shouldn’t expect to see this though, because OkHttp honors the max concurrent stream limit.

Note that connection creation is racy. This limit may only become known to OkHttp after it has created multiple streams. In such cases the server is supposed to permit these streams.

Comment: Thanks jesse wilson, what about 1) Does okhttp support connection pooling for http2 client ? The offifical doc square.github.io/okhttp says this "Connection pooling reduces request latency (if HTTP/2 isn’t available)".  2) What do you mean when you say "This is honored" ? what is the value client sents to reciever as part of settings frame for max concurrent sessions.   3) When you say okhttp honors max concurrent streams, are you saying client knows about the active streams on server end and prevents sending streams once threshold is met ?

Comment: 1. All HTTP connections are pooled, including HTTP/2 connections. 2. The default max value is implemented. 3. Yes. If an HTTP/2 connection cannot carry a call because it has reached its limit a new HTTP connection will be established.